# How to create Record-Triggered flow with scheduled paths for sending email alert to user if last login is >30 days

Tags: visual-workflow, user, user-record, recordtriggeredflow, loginflow

Looking to create a flow with 2 scheduled paths to 1) send an email to the user if they have not logged in for over 30 days 2) thereafter to send an email to the Admin if the user's login is over 35 days to deactivate the user

Currently have a record-triggered flow with 2 scheduled paths:

[image]

[image]

As LastLoginDate cannot be used as a formula in flows, I created 2 Date/Time formulas for checking the last dates Now() - 30 and another Now() - 35

I'm not advanced with building flows so any help would be appreciated in troubleshooting what to do with the 'Run Immediately' path. Should I be using another decision element?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should be using Scheduled-Triggered flows rather than record-triggered.  Since you are checking for a condition that does not occur (i.e. the user does not login), a record-triggered flow is not practical because nothing is happening to trigger it.

On the other hand, a scheduled flow will run daily to check that nothing has changed and then do your actions.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for coming back to me. I did think about this too but how would I use the Last Login Date field as it doesn't seem to be an option in the Scheduled-Triggered flow?